# stick an extra element into the front of the sequence defined by an xml schema complex type

Tags: xsd

xs:extension allows adding elements to the end. Is there a way to extend a type and add elements to the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no. If you plan ahead when defining the base type, you can insert wildcards at expected extension points and then derive from it restriction, replacing the wildcard(s) with actual element contents.